# Finding maximum of the selected column in loaded csv data in Javascript

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

```
function myFunction() {
dd = document.getElementsByClassName("addin");
ds = document.getElementsByClassName("slidfi");

var arr = [];

for(var i = 0;i< dd.length;i++){
var obj = {};
obj["check"] = dd[i].checked;
obj["value"] = ds[i].value;
obj["headers"] = dd[i].value;
arr.push(obj)
}
return arr;   
}
```

status variable in the below function have details of value and status[i]["header"] which is column value for corresponding header and I want to divide each of the value with the **max** value in the whole column. It should be basically something like this -

```
temp.push((d[status[i]["headers"]]/Math.max(temp)) * status[i]["value"])
```

but I am not able to get **max** for entire column.

Here is the current code but also want to take **max** and divide by each value to normalize it then multiply by **status[i]["value"]**.

```
function UpdatedData() {
var status = myFunction();

d3.csv('cars.csv', function(error, data) {
data.forEach(function(d){

var temp=[];

for(var i=0;i<status.length;i++){
    if (status[i]["check"]){
      temp.push(d[status[i]["headers"]] * status[i]["value"]) 
    }
  }
});
});
}
```

**status** is an array with this format.

```
0 {check: false, value: "0.5", headers: "W"}
1 {check: false, value: "0.5", headers: "X"}
2 {check: true, value: "0.5", headers: "Y"}
3 {check: true, value: "0.5", headers: "Z"}
```

So last two are checked,so in this case **temp** will be an array of dim 2. One will be correspond to header **Y** and other to corresponding header **Z**. I want the **max** for the all column value corresponding to **Y** and **Z** but not the max within **Y** and **Z**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your question's title is a bit different from your question's text, I'll address the question's **title** only. I hope that it suits you.

You can find the maximum of any column using the D3 method [d3.max](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/master/README.md#max), which:

> Returns the maximum value in the given array using natural order. If the array is empty, returns undefined. An optional accessor function may be specified, which is equivalent to calling array.map(accessor) before computing the maximum value.

So, given this bogus CSV:

```
foo, bar, baz
12, 14, 65
26, 75, 39
67, 11, 93
19, 42, 17
```

We can find the maximum of the `foo` column with:

```
var maxFoo = d3.max(data, function(d){ return d.foo});
```

For finding the maximum of two or more columns, we can simply create an array with the individual maximum values:

```
var maxFooBar1 = d3.max([maxFoo, maxBar]);
```

Or, alternatively, we can find the maximum in each object:

```
var maxFooBar2 = d3.max(data, function(d){ return d3.max([d.foo, d.bar])});
```

Here is a demo (I'm using a pre element to simulate the CSV):

```js
var data = d3.csvParse(d3.select("#csv").text());

data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.foo = +d.foo;
  d.bar = +d.bar;
  d.baz = +d.baz;
})

var maxFoo = d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return d.foo
});

var maxBar = d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return d.bar
});

var maxFooBar1 = d3.max([maxFoo, maxBar]);

var maxFooBar2 = d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return d3.max([d.foo, d.bar])
});

console.log("The max of foo is: " + maxFoo)
console.log("The max of foo and bar is (method 1): " + maxFooBar1)
console.log("The max of foo and bar is (method 2): " + maxFooBar2)
```

```css
pre {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<pre id="csv">foo,bar,baz
12,14,65
26,75,39
67,11,93
19,42,17</pre>
```

Comment: I don't know why you think so, because i have said in question title itself "Selected Column" which is in the question also, last two Y and Z. The one you suggested is possible when you already know and try with all.

Comment: That's so easy, it's just a matter of using bracket notation in the object... anyway, I'm going to delete this.

Comment: You don't have to, I am getting some idea from it.

Comment: var maxFoo = [];
for(var i=0;i<status.length;i++){
    if (status[i]["check"]){
       maxFoo[i] = d3.max(data, function(d){ return d[status[i]["headers"]]});
    }

}
not getting correct maximum

Comment: Please, copy/paste your data array structure (not all of it, just a few rows).

Answer (score 2):

You need to calculate the max of the entire column in a loop first, doing something like

```
maxTemp = 0;
for(var i=0;i<status.length;i++){
    if (status[i]["check"]){
      if(maxTemp < d[status[i]["headers"]])
          maxTemp = d[status[i]["headers"]];
    }
}
```

Then divide the using the `maxTemp` in another loop

```
for(var i=0;i<status.length;i++){
    temp.push((d[status[i]["headers"]]/maxTemp) * status[i]["value"])
}
```

**Pseudo Code **

```
maxTemp = 0;
data.forEach(function(d){
    //some code
    if(maxTemp < d[status[i]["headers"]])
              maxTemp = d[status[i]["headers"]];
        }
})

data.forEach(function(d){
    //some code
    temp.push(value /maxTemp)
})
```

Comment: Check the question please, I have updated once again after going through your answer.

Comment: Ok I wrote the loop wrong. My point was you need to calculate the max of the column in the 1st foreach loop, and use the foreacg again to divide the value using the max calculated.

Comment: it means maxTemp should be an array right instead of being normal variable? Can you update your answer please if you got it right?

Comment: I'll write a pseudo code to make you understand what I mean. You be the judge if I got it right.

Comment: Yeah Sure, I will see if that's what I want. Thanks for helping